# Reactjs - reset tab index on action change in material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using the `Tabs` of `material-ui`. The swipe-able tab is opened on `onTouchTap`, its working fine but the `tab` index is not getting reset to `0` on new action, its showing the last tab index, not the `tab` with index `0`. I tried to create a function to change the state to 0, but its saying that the state cannot be changed inside render. Kindly help, I am new to Reactjs.

```
class ModelDetail extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      slideIndex: 0,
    };
  }

  handleChange (value) {
    this.setState({
      slideIndex: value,
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Tabs onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} value={this.state.slideIndex}>
          <Tab label="Input Parameters" value={0} style={styles.heading} />
          <Tab label="Benchmark Output" value={1} style={styles.heading} />
          <Tab label="Output Figures" value={2} style={styles.heading} />
        </Tabs>
        <SwipeableViews index={this.state.slideIndex}  onChangeIndex={this.handleChange.bind(this)}>
          ...
          ...
        </SwipeableViews>
      </div>
    )}
```

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for I have done so much effort but didn't get success but finally i found this and all are done Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried to create a function to change the state to 0, but its saying
>   that the state cannot be changed inside render.

Everytime you change the state, component renders, if you unconditionally update state in render, it will create an infinte loop of component rendering. So, you obviously cannot do that.

If you wish to change the state, add an event handler and change state on the occurrence of event.

Comment: Thank you. I was about to do that.

Comment: @Jeril Please accept the answer if you think it solves your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Internally material-ui uses **react-swipeable-views** so instead of calling custom event handler its better to use library's method named as `onSwitching`
you can read whole documentation here

> https://github.com/oliviertassinari/react-swipeable-views

For example

```
        <SwipeableViews
          index={index}
          onChangeIndex={ onTabChange }
          onSwitching = { this.onSwipe }
        >
          {views}
        </SwipeableViews>
```